# How to create new object name by user input

Tags: java, object

I want to create new object and to give it user input name.

Example user input "robert" wil match to:

```
 Action robert = new Action();
 robert.eat();
```

What do I need to change in the program so I can create a new object with a dynamic name?
Many Thanks.
I write the next code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Human {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );

        String first_name;
        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        first_name = user_input.next( );//robert

        System.out.println("You are " + first_name);//robert

        Action first_name = new Action();
        Food orange = new Food();
        robert.eat(orange);

    }

}
```

Comment: Objects don't generally have names. You're talking about the name of a *variable*, which is entirely different. If you want your object to have a name, it should have a field to remember its name, and you should probably pass the name into the constructor.

Comment: You are wrong, YOu are mixing variable name and user's name!

Comment: Why do you want to give a dynamic name to the variable if nobody is going to see it in runtime?

Comment: I have a feeling you are looking for [maps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), which allow you to access an object using a key, which can be a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java, unlike other languages, does not have a way to dynamically create variable names. Variable names are declared in the code. In order to achieve what you're trying to do, look into the Collection's [Map interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). This will allow you to "map" a user given name to some value.

Quick example:

```
//1) Setup the mapping, 
//The first parameter to put() is the key (perhaps a user given name?) 
//and the second parameter is actual value you want to map for that key.
//note that although I'm using a String as the key and a String as the value
//You can use pretty much any object as the value. Keys are recommended to be
//immutable objects (a String is a good one)
Map<String,String> mMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
mMap.put("John", "Orange");
mMap.put("Steve","Apple");

//2) Once the map is setup, you can then retrieve values given a key:
System.out.println("John's fruit is: "+mMap.get("John"));
```

[More info here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html).

Answer (score 0):

Variable names cant be specified(created) at run time(dynamically).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. How can you declare the name of the Class object as a variable.