# Generate new Variables in java

Tags: java, variables, dynamic

I'd like to automaticly create a new Variable for my Storage.

It should work like:

```
int var_count = getConfig().getInt("var_count");
++var_count;

int "var"+var_count = 123
```

If var_count is for example 4, it should generate a Variable named var4.

Comment: You need to use another language.

Comment: Is there a certain thing that you're trying to do with this? It is possible that a structure such as a List or Map would be more suited to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Lord, this has been asked and answered too many times on this site to count. Please consider searching before asking such common questions.

Comment: Please also look at [Assigning variables with dynamic names in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6729605), [Create Dynamic Object with specific name in java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19526359), [How to create new object name by user input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20359064), [How to instantiate variable with name from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24005132), ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to automaticly create a new Variable for my Storage.

You can't. You could (however) make a `Map<String, Integer>` and store arbitrary key-value pairs. Something like

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("var" + var_count, 123);
System.out.println(map.get("var" + var_count));
```